# How to remove datetime which starts before endtime of the previous datetime

Tags: python

I am going to make event time list where duplicate date time and starting time of a next event is starts before ending time of a previous event does not exist in the list.
I converted date time to Julian date. And the list is as below:

```
Before converting to Julian date:

   timename      starttime                endtime
1  20170103      2017/01/03T05:36:05      2017/01/03T13:42:04
2  20170103      2017/01/03T14:00:04      2017/01/03T20:30:07
3  20170112      2017/01/12T16:24:05      2017/01/12T23:42:05
4  20170114      2017/01/14T05:00:05      2017/01/14T09:42:06
5  20170114      2017/01/14T08:24:05      2017/01/14T14:18:05
6  20170117      2017/01/17T21:49:12      2017/01/18T02:30:06
7  20170119      2017/01/19T12:24:05      2017/01/19T18:30:06
8  20170124      2017/01/24T15:36:05      2017/01/25T04:42:07
9  20170125      2017/01/25T16:00:05      2017/01/26T14:30:05
...
```

```
After converting to Julian date:

  timename   starttime           endtime
1 2457756.5  2457756.733391204   2457757.07087963
2 2457756.5  2457757.0833796295  2457757.354247685
3 2457765.5  2457766.1833912036  2457766.4875578703
4 2457767.5  2457767.7083912035  2457767.9042361113
5 2457767.5  2457767.85005787    2457768.0958912037
6 2457770.5  2457771.4091666667  2457771.604236111
7 2457772.5  2457773.016724537   2457773.2709027776
8 2457777.5  2457778.1500578704  2457778.695914352
9 2457778.5  2457779.166724537   2457780.104224537
...
```

I want to remove if first row of strattime and endtime includes second row start time. Otherwise, skip. For example, you can see that the 5th row starttime (2017/01/14T08:24:05) is starts before the 4th row endtime (2017/01/14T09:42:06). So it includes 5th row starttime. But I need to remove them and get only times which starts after previous endtime.

Here is my attempt.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

infilename2 = 'D:/My works/C3_jdate/2017.txt'
outfilename2 = 'D:/My works/2017_1.txt'


lines_seen = set()
outfile = open(outfilename2, "w")
df = pd.read_csv(infilename2,sep = '\t', engine='python', header=0)
    
t = df['timename']
t1 = df['timename']
st = df['starttime']
et = df['endtime']

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if t[i] != t1[j]:
            pass
        elif t[i] == t1[j]:
            if (st[i]<st[j] and et[i]<=st[j]):
                
                line1 = df.to_string()
                if line1 not in lines_seen:
                    outfile.write(line1)
                    lines_seen.add(line1)
outfile.close()
```

But still, output is the same with input.
Please share any idea for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

For each row, you could subtract the current previous `endtime` from the current `starttime`, using Pandas:

```
df['diff'] = df['starttime'] - df['endtime'].shift(1)
```

Here, [.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) moves the rows up by the specified period, in this case, 1.

Do make sure that your data is sorted accordingly.

Then, you can filter out the rows where `diff` is negative (keep the rows where time difference between current starttime and previous endtime is > 0:

```
filtered_df = df[df['diff'] > pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work:

```py
# Get time between current start and last end
time_from_last_endtime = df["starttime"] - df["endtime"].shift(fill_value=0)
df[time_from_last_endtime >= 0]
```